# On iOS, can you make a synchronous network request (but not on the main thread) and still get progress callbacks (on a separate, non-main thread)?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

On iOS, can you make a synchronous network request (off the main thread) and get progress callbacks (on a separate, non-main thread)?

I have have a serial (one-operation-at-a-time) background queue that runs all of time-consuming jobs that don't need to finish *right* now. I do want to show progress for the download jobs though. It doesn't look like you can instantiate an `NSURLConnection` and configure a delegate, start synchronous connection, and then get progress callbacks.

Is there a way to make a synchronous request on that background queue (synchronous in that the job behind it doesn't start until its done), and still get `setProgress:` callbacks which could be sent to update a progressbar? (Callbacks would have to be on a different queue thread, since my serial queue's thread is blocked until the request is finished.)

[Apple's docs for NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say that the synchronous request is actually built on top of the asynchronous behind the scenes. Do I have to re-implement that? I need a way to block a thread until the request finishes/fails. The best leads I have so far are `NSOperationQueue`'s  `waitUntilFinished` method, but I don't want to start async and continually poll on the synchronous method.

> **NSURLConnection Discussion**
>
> A synchronous load is built on top of the asynchronous loading code made available by the class. The calling thread is blocked while the asynchronous loading system performs the URL load on a thread spawned specifically for this load request. No special threading or run loop configuration is necessary in the calling thread in order to perform a synchronous load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reimplementing a synchronous request on top of an asynchronous request is not that hard. You just need to manually spin the thread's run loop until you see that the request has finished (or failed). Here's a rough example:

```
NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:queryURL];
// Start the download and wait until it finishes
self.downloadFinished = NO;
self.downloader = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:downloadRequest delegate:self];

while (!self.isDownloadFinished)
 {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
 }
```

Here are the relevant NSURLConnectionDelegate methods:

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
 {
    self.downloadFinished = YES;
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
 {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    self.receivedData = nil;
    self.downloadFinished = YES;
 }
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking. Thank you for suggesting NSRunLoop, I didn't know about that. My concern is that the while loop would run so fast it would uselessly take up CPU. Why is that not the case?

Comment: `-[NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate:]` doesn't return immediately. It waits for input from at least one of its attached input sources (which in this case includes the NSURLConnection) which it processes before returning. If it times out by reaching the specified date, it will return too. In other words, that while loop won't be spinning any faster than needed to process the connection, and NSRunLoop takes care of efficiently waiting. You can read more in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsrunloop_Class/Reference/Reference.html