# IPhone Device Orientation - How Main UI thread is affected?

Tags: iphone

I am developing a hello world application in iphone OS 6.0. Whenever a screen is rendered, a web service call is made to the server. But, i am making the web service call in the same main thread without starting in a seperate thread.

However, whenever i rotate the device to landscape mode, the web service call is stopped. Again when i rotate the device to portrait mode, web service call is started.

Any idea on why this happens ... Thanks in advance.

EDIT
I tested the application using iOS instruments (Network Monitor). I understand that device orientation did not stop the network operation.

Comment: You should avoid making network calls on the UI thread altogether.  The UI needs those processing cycles to keep the display responsive.  That includes handling autorotation.

Comment: Yes i am aware of Asynchronous networking. But my doubt here is ... Whenever, i change the device orientation will the main UI thread gets stopped and restarted ?? Or How UI thread behaves when the screen orientation occurs ?

Comment: In Android mobile OS, Activity gets rendered again whenever the orientation occues. Does iOS behaves similarly ? How UI thread behaves when Orientation occurs ??

Comment: paste some code to identify....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following links helped me arrive at a solution.

[On iOS, can you make a synchronous network request (but not on the main thread) and still get progress callbacks (on a separate, non-main thread)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471896/on-ios-can-you-make-a-synchronous-network-request-but-not-on-the-main-thread)
http://tewha.net/2012/06/networking-using-nsurlconnection/

I understand that in Iphone, UI rendering happens in the Main Thread. So, i can control the application behavior with respect to device orientation similar to android OS.

Adding to this, I need not perform the network code in asynchronous mode. I can perform the synchronous network operation in a seperate thread. This solves my issue.

Thanks for all ...